# Side effect for nodesize in R randomForest ?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, random-forest

I'm currently working on a randomForest model. In my configuration I realize that high nodesize values is the configuration which outperform using crossvalidation.

But then I realized something strange.

Here is a reproduicible piece of code :

For nodesize = nrow(data)+4 :

```
library(randomForest)
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

n = 10

sigma = 0.4

X = runif(n)
Y = runif(n)

Z = X^2+X*Y+Y+sigma*rnorm(n)

Data = data.table(X,Y,Z)

model = randomForest(formula = as.formula('Z ~ X + Y'),data = Data,mtry =        1,tree= 500,nodesize = n+4,do.trace = TRUE)

pred = predict(model,Data)
print(pred)
1.041549 1.036075 1.266310 1.324197 1.308377 1.480041 1.691081 1.752463 1.203856 1.306943
```

For nodesize = nrow(data)+5

```
library(randomForest)
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

n = 10

sigma = 0.4

X = runif(n)
Y = runif(n)

Z = X^2+X*Y+Y+sigma*rnorm(n)

Data = data.table(X,Y,Z)

model = randomForest(formula = as.formula('Z ~ X + Y'),data = Data,mtry =        1,tree= 500,nodesize = n+5,do.trace = TRUE)

pred = predict(model,Data)
print(pred)
1.330427 1.330427 1.330427 1.330427 1.330427 1.330427 1.330427 1.330427 1.330427 1.330427
```

The prediction are the same for any observation from nodesize = n+5.

This is the case for any value of n (n = 20000 also).

For me the nodesize is the minimal number of records in a node in order for a split to be performed. So this means that if we have n records, the trees are grown by sampling n+4 observations with replacements. So if nodesize > n+4 no split is performed and the trees return global means : that's why the same prediction is attributed to every observations. Does that makes sense ? Is there a parameter to indicate how many sample are drawn from the original dataset ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nodesize is the minimum size of terminal nodes not the size needed to split the nodes further, note terminal nodes are the leaves. Branches won't be created unless nodesize is <n. if that is your sample size. Also the sampsize option witin randomFirests gives the size of sample to draw from the original dataset.

Answer (score 0):

@Morgan is right that there was a misunderstanding regarding what `nodesize` does. It's the minimum size of any terminal node. But still, the behavior of `randomForest` seems unexpected (bug?). It does actually create branches if `n <= nodesize <= n+5`, that's what you've found.

If nodesize is 10 (the size of the sample), there should not be any splits, but `randomForest` still makes a split that splits off several observations. It also does that when nodesize is one of `11:14` (not shown here):

```
n = 10
sigma = 0.4
set.seed(100)
X = runif(n)
set.seed(200)
Y = runif(n)

set.seed(1)
Z = X^2+X*Y+Y+sigma*rnorm(n)

Data = data.frame(X,Y,Z)

#
# mtry = p, replace = F and sampsize = n to eliminate randomness
#
model = randomForest(formula = Z ~ X + Y, data = Data,
                     mtry = 2, ntree = 50, nodesize = 10, replace = F, sampsize = n)

grid <- expand.grid(X = seq(from = min(Data$X), to = max(Data$X), length.out = 100),
                    Y = seq(from = min(Data$Y), to = max(Data$Y), length.out = 100))
grid$grid_preds <- predict(model, grid)
ggplot(grid, aes(x = X, y = Y)) + geom_point(aes(color = grid_preds)) +
    geom_point(data = Data, aes(x = X, y = Y, size = 4), color = "blue") +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image: plot1]

If you set `nodesize` to `n + 5` or higher `randomForest` does not make any splits anymore, as expected:

```
model = randomForest(formula = Z ~ X + Y, data = Data,
                     mtry = 2, ntree = 50, nodesize = 15, replace = F, sampsize = n)

grid <- expand.grid(X = seq(from = min(Data$X), to = max(Data$X), length.out = 100),
                    Y = seq(from = min(Data$Y), to = max(Data$Y), length.out = 100))
grid$grid_preds <- predict(model, grid)
ggplot(grid, aes(x = X, y = Y, color = grid_preds)) + geom_point()
```

[image: plot2]

As a comparison, `ranger` shows the expected behavior and does not attempt any splits if `min.node.size >= n`:

```
library(ranger)
rang = ranger(Z ~ X + Y, data = Data, write.forest = T,
              replace = F, sample.fraction = 1,
              mtry = 2, num.trees = 50, min.node.size = 10)

grid$grid_preds <- predict(rang, grid)$prediction
ggplot(grid, aes(x = X, y = Y, color = grid_preds)) + geom_point()
```

[image: plot3]

By the way, the `n+5` rule in `randomForest` also holds for `n` other than 10. I'm wondering too what's going on there.